# Clear search history in ebook reader App (Desire S)

Tags: ebook-reader, htc-desire-s, search-history

Is there any way to clear search history in ebook reader App on Desire S?
(It is the default reader App for ebook on HTC desire S).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [HTC Desire S user guide](http://static.vip.hr/hwdb/images/uploaded/bazaznanja/2204689_HTC_Desire_S.pdf) in PDF, but I couldn't find there anything about clear search history in the section Reading eBook (pages 148-151). So, being that the default eBook reader, I guess that clearing search history is not possible unless you clear data from that app.

Comment: Clearing data from the app clears also list of all books that have been loaded on the app.